# elasticquent/Elasticquent paginate issue, It returns all data

Tags: laravel, elasticsearch, pagination, laravel-5

I'm using  'elasticquent/Elasticquent' elasticsearch package for Laravel 5.2

here is my code

```
 $videos = Video::searchByQuery(['match_all' => []],null, null, 300, null, ['id' => 'desc']) ->paginate(42);
```

I want to get last 300 items with pagination 42 item per page,
but it still returns all 300 items, not  42.
Does anyone knows how to solve that problem?

Comment: are you sure this model provides pagination? Pagination is Elastic Search in general is a bit tricky.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in the documentation found [here](https://github.com/elasticquent/Elasticquent), you can query by using the following function:

```
public static function searchByQuery(
    $query = null, 
    $aggregations = null, 
    $sourceFields = null, 
    $limit = null, 
    $offset = null, 
    $sort = null
)
```

Parameter 4 (`$limit`) and 5 (`$offset`) can be used to create pagination.

---

In your case the following query would grants you 42 results, from offset, 0.

```
$videos = Video::searchByQuery(['match_all' => []],null, null, 42, 0, ['id' => 'desc']);
```

Answer (score 0):

> **elasticquent/Elasticquent paginate issue**

in this package paginate function have same name with paginate func in laravel.
change name paginate function by hold CTRL + click on function then use it.